# Change the default view in Explorer. Windows 8 / Registry / VBS

Tags: windows-8, vbscript, registry, explorer

**Base:** I have a short piece of a registry changing vb script.

```
key = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams"
result = wmireg.CreateKey(HKCU, key)

binaer = Array(8,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,229,37,241,101,225,123,16,72,186,157,210,113,200,67,44,227,4,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,67,0,0,0)

result = wmireg.SetBinaryValue(HKCU, key,"Settings",binaer)

key ="Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Defaults"
result = wmireg.CreateKey(HKCU, key)
binaer = Array(28,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,144,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,240,240,240,240,20,0,3,0,144,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,48,0,0,0,253,223,223,253,15,0,4,0,32,0,16,0,40,0,60,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,42,1,96,0,120,0,120,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
result = wmireg.SetBinaryValue(HKCU,key,"{F3364BA0-65B9-11CE-A9BA-00AA004AE837}", binaer)
```

**Problem:** In this snippet the default view of the explorer will be set to tile-view. Everything works fine in **Windows XP**. Now I am going to translate this to **Windows 8**, but with **no** success.

I used the [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to figure out the registry key values which will be set if I do this step manually using the UI.

**In Windows 8, the key:**

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Settings
```

**Will be set to:**

```
08 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 E5 25 F1 65
```

**And the key:**

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Defaults\{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}
```

**Will be set to**

```
1C 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

In Windows XP I can change this values by the script, restart (or logout-login) and the default view is the tiles view. But in Windows 8 nothing happens.

I changed the vbs with the Windows 8 values, now if the script is complete the value in the registry will be successfully modified. But if I open my explorer there is no other view applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research with [RegShot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regshot/) I figured out that you have to **delete these keys** first:

1. `Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags`
2. `Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU`

Windows does not need these keys to be consistent. If they are missing the system creates them on the fly with basic settings.

**After removing these keys** you can set your default view by **setting the right bytes to these keys**:

1. `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Settings`
2. `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Streams\Defaults\{5C4F28B5-F869-4E84-8E60-F11DB97C5CC7}`

With the [RegShot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/regshot/) tool you can find out the right bytes for Symbole-, Details- or List-View. If anyone needs them leave a comment. I do not want to write a ~40x20 Byte-Matrix to this post ;).

With this method you do not need a restart or a logoff to **change your default folder view for all folders**.
This method does also **reset all** saved folder-views and set the default one.